# Can I make IntelliJ debug my android applications via the device instead of the emulator?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've been searching all evening, and I can't find a way to have IntelliJ deploy my android application to my device via USB debugging. I can't see any options to specify the target other than a virtual device.

I have device drivers installed, and all updates available to IntelliJ X and the SDK.

Is it even possible? Or only for eclipse?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes it is possible - just specify in the Run/Debug configuration no virtual device to use and IJ will prompt you where to run the app. If the devices is connected, it will be listed and you can just select it.

This works very well here on OS X.

> On windows you may need to install the driver. 
>   Download through the SDK manager Extras-> Google USB driver. 
>   Then go to your SDK\Extras\Google\USB_driver\ folder, 
>   right-click on android_winusb.inf and choose Install.

Comment: Also if a device is connected via USB, IntelliJ will not start virtual device but rather install the app directly on the phone.

Comment: How does it do this? I can't find the settings

Comment: Thanks. This was the last piece I needed. I USB debug my Galaxy Tab from IDEA now. Win 7, with Samsung Kies installed to get the right USB driver.

Comment: Just to elaborate the driver issue: For some devides, you also need to install OEM USB driver. ex. Nexus 7 needs a driver from google supplied by SDK manager. [google developper site](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver)